# When I use Navicat client to link a SQL Server database with the sa user, there is an error "client unable to establish connection 10054"

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have enable the `sa` user, and can log on by using SSMS; but if I use navicat to link it, there is an error 10054.

[image]

Comment: As a general rule, you should **never ever** actually **use** the `sa` account for any applications and / or any programmatic work. This is strictly an admin account, and it's best to not even use it for admin purposes, either ....

Comment: many thanks，marc_s,your suggestion is good，I have solved this problem by modified the TLS1.0，enable it in regedit,then restart the server.it works.